# I cannot find information about some chips in 3 stage LNA circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf, lna

[image]

Hi, here you can see 3-stage LNA circuit. I want to know information about two chips(6 pins) with R8 mark at the top. Also, 4 chips with D4 mark with 3 pins at right side. Is there anyone who has a good intuition of this?

Comment: Can you tell us about the part that these components are in? Perhaps a manufacturer and model number for the overall board/assembly?

Comment: It is made from MITEQ, and model name is IDM215A75-2020-140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [BCM857](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BCM857BV_BS_DS.pdf) dual BJT and [HSMP3804](https://www.rf-microwave.com/en/hewlett-packard/hsmp-3804/common-cathode-pair-pin-diode/hsmp-3804/) PIN diode. Maybe.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your information helped me a lot. :)